# How to read GPS signal strength in Windows Mobile?

Tags: .net, windows-mobile, compact-framework, gps

How can I read the GPS signal strength from my Compact .NET app in Windows Mobile 5 and/or 6? I've only seen accessors for GPRS and Wi-Fi signal strength in the API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the [GPS Application Windows Mobile code sample at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb158699.aspx).  It's what taught me most of what I needed to know to get started with [Hineini](http://hineini.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Thanks for the useful link! Unfortunately it looks like I'd have to connect to GPS first and then check the signal strength of each satellite, which is a shame because I wanted to know the signal strength without having to connect (as it can be time-consuming).